# how to stop a function when id div is called?

Tags: jquery

i need your help. I have 2 divs inside one container div with id ´rfsh-sidebar-2´. I set a function in wich every 10 seconds, it changes from the first div to the second one. But is a loop (when the second div finish its 10 seconds, it comes to the first div, and so on. Well, i need to stop this loop when the last div (the second one) is called.

My code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Ad rotation</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rfsh-sidebar-2">
<!-- div1 -->
<div>
    <div style="background-color: aqua; width: 300px; height: 250px;">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- div2 -->
<div id="stop">
    <div style="background-color: orangered; width: 300px; height: 
    250px;">
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#rfsh-sidebar-2 > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
$('#rfsh-sidebar-2 > div:first')
.fadeOut(1)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#rfsh-sidebar-2');
},  4200);


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `clearInterval()` ?

Comment: I can't see an idea behind using `setInterval` and `clearInterval` in your case .. in this case you need just to delay the action of show/hide div .. you can just use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`clearInterval` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).

You must declare a variable for it:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
$('#rfsh-sidebar-2 > div:first')
.fadeOut(1)
.next()
.fadeIn(1000)
.end()
.appendTo('#rfsh-sidebar-2');
},  4200);
```

And then:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I set it as you show, but what happen is that loop start with first div and stop there. It never continue looping to the second div. I want that loop start at first div, and after x seconds, continue it way to the second div, and stop there (dont start the loop again, finish loop at last div).

Comment: got it! i found the solution. What i did was delet ".appendTo('#rfsh-sidebar-2');" line because .appendTo make cycle start again. Thanks for your help